# apxs cannot install mod_cloudflare on centos

Tags: apache-2.2, centos, cloudflare

**[ Linux - CentOS - Apache 2.2 - mod_cloudflare - apxs2 ]**

I have changed my nameservers to point to CloudFlare. The problem is that all the IP addresses are coming in as CloudFlare's. This is no good, because I have to monitor and block some specific traffic. mod_cloudflare is supposed to resolve this but I have been unable to get this installed. The command in the [documentation](https://github.com/cloudflare/mod_cloudflare) uses apxs2. I can't figure out how to install this, or if it just means for 'apache 2.4'. I'm running 2.2.3, and I can use 'apxs'.

When I run:

```
apxs -aic mod_cloudflare.c
```

I get the error

```
apxs:Error: Command failed with rc=65536
```

Does this mean I need apxs2 or something else? How do I get mod_cloudflare working on my server?

I appreciate any help, the documentation is vague and limited.

Comment: Do you need to Apache to block in realtime?

Comment: Also, is there any other error printed before the one mentioned?

Comment: No just the one error. CloudFlare does the blocking, but I try to identify crawlers through behavioral tracking. For instance if the user loads the background texture image, and downloads the css file associated with a page. I've noticed CloudFlare can't get all the bots and some bots come directly by IP, bypassing CloudFlare. So I have to identify them before they get a chunk of my content.

Comment: Also+, did you install the RPM? If so, please do `rpm -ql mod_clodflare`

Comment: package mod_cloudflare is not installed

Comment: I was following the directions for compiling from the source mod_cloudflare.c

Comment: Try getting the RPM for your architecture (32bit/64bit) from https://www.cloudflare.com/resources-downloads

Comment: The first link "Apache module: mod_cloudflare" is the set of directions I followed originally.

Comment: Towards the bottom of that section, there's a number of links for different OS. There's https://github.com/downloads/cloudflare/mod_cloudflare/mod_cloudflare-1.1.1-1.i586.rpm (32bit) and https://github.com/downloads/cloudflare/mod_cloudflare/mod_cloudflare-1.1.1-1.x86_64.rpm (64bit)

Comment: I've added this as my answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fetch the RPM for your platform from https://www.cloudflare.com/resources-downloads:
https://github.com/downloads/cloudflare/mod_cloudflare/mod_cloudflare-1.1.1-1.i586.rpm (32bit) and https://github.com/downloads/cloudflare/mod_cloudflare/mod_cloudflare-1.1.1-1.x86_64.rpm (64bit)

Install: `rpm -ivh mod_cloudflare-1.1.1-1.*`

Edit `/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf`

```
LoadModule cloudflare_module /usr/lib64/apache2/mod_cloudflare.so
<IfModule mod_cloudflare.c>
    CloudFlareRemoteIPHeader CF-Connecting-IP
    CloudFlareRemoteIPTrustedProxy 204.93.240.0/24 204.93.177.0/24 199.27.128.0/21 173.245.48.0/20 103.22.200.0/22 141.101.64.0/18 108.162.192.0/18
    #DenyAllButCloudFlare
</IfModule>
```

On 32bit change `lib64` to `lib`

Comment: I'm awarding you the points for being the only person to respond with an answer and it might work for some people. I actually tried both of these and it did not resolve my issue. I instead worked around by checking for the CloudFlare Remote IP header and setting it as the remote IP in my code if it exists. Thanks, Fuzzyfelt.

Answer (score 0):

A bit late to the party, but I received the error:

```
libtool: install: cp .libs/mod_cloudflare.so /usr/lib64/httpd/modules/mod_cloudflare.so
cp: cannot create regular file '/usr/lib64/httpd/modules/mod_cloudflare.so': Permission denied
apxs:Error: Command failed with rc=65536
```

And the reason, as stated in the error, is due to `Permission denied`.

I was able to execute the command with `sudo`:

```
sudo apxs -a -i -c mod_cloudflare.c
```